# Cant scan display image charset qr zxing android

Tags: java, android, zxing, qr-code

Sorry for my english. I cant scan qr image, I have this "???????". I use zxing library. I try but not success. Bellow my code. String equals russian charset. I don't know why scan instance symbol to ??????.

```
final QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
ImageView tnsd_iv_qr = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.qrImage);
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
byte[] b = null;
try {
    // Convert a string to UTF-8 bytes in a ByteBuffer
    ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(summ.getText().toString() + "/"
            + getNumber.substring(1) + "/"
            + getName + "/" 
            + getIdDepartament + "/"
            + getIdUser + "/"
            + getSpinnerItem));
    b = bbuf.array();
} catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
    //
}

String data;

try {
     data = new String(b, "UTF-8");
     Hashtable<EncodeHintType, String> hints = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType, String>(2);
     hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "UTF-8");

        ByteMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(   data

                ,BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 512, 512, hints);

        int width = 512;
        int height = 512;
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                if (bitMatrix.get(x, y)==0)
                    bmp.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK);
                else
                    bmp.setPixel(x, y, Color.WHITE);
            }
        }
        tnsd_iv_qr.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    } catch (WriterException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I fix this line

```
data = new String(b, "ISO-8859-1");
                         Hashtable<EncodeHintType, String> hints = new Hashtable<EncodeHintType, String>(2);
                         hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "ISO-8859-1");
```

and its work!